# Pytorch Splitting Batch/tensor

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I am attempting to split a batch in a forward loss function and I am having problems doing so.
The batch size prior to augmentation is 256, after augmentation "images" is of size [512,3,96,96] using print(images.size()) | where [batch_size, layers, height, width].

I would like to split the 256 non-augmented images from the augmented ones to perform a contrast score comparing the two split tensors.

> images, list = batch #

I attempted to split them after my augmentations and convolutions when it was [512,128] but got two tensors size [512,64] instead.

If I am thinking about this right expecting a split of two tensors [256,128], if I am thinking about the above sizes properly..